# How to express a dependency graph with multiple tree roots in celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, dependency-graph

Let's say I have two trees which depend on a common task T:

```
  A       X
 / \     / \
B   C   Y   Z
     \ /
      T
```

How may I represent such a dependency with celery primitives (`chain`, `group`, `chord`, `chunk`, etc.)?

(Sadly, not enough points to create the tag celery, if someone could help, I'd be really grateful)

Comment: celery tag already exists. i added it to your Q